# How do I position facet-grid in ggplot2 along the x axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet-grid

I am drawing facet_grid using code

```
mg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_point()
mg + facet_grid(vs + am ~ gear)
```

which gives the following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oakCp.jpg

[image]

I would like to add some space where I have marked an arrow in the image, please can someone help with this.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this

`mg <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_point() + 
   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(7,35), expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(5,35,5)) +
  facet_grid(vs + am ~ gear) 
mg`

the expand will usually add a bit of space and you can play with that or you can adjust the limits. When you do this it throws off the sequence of numbers so you have to set that as well...

Comment: Thanks for this Bill. I tried the same on my code and it worked fine, but it added a spacing for all the facets, and I was only trying to add the space to the first one.

Comment: Oh, I see - no idea on that one. The alternative is to make all the graphs and use patchwork to make your own combined plot but that would be a lot more work

Comment: Hi I looked into this a bit more as I wait for other projects to run. It looks like it was suggested to Hadley but has and will not be done or a while. They also suggested in the end to use Patchwork to do individual plots that are then combined but this could be a lot of work if you have a lot of papers.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using `expand_limits()` to fix your problem.
Also use `strpi.placement="outside"` inside `theme()` so the graph looks little pretty.

```
mg=ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + geom_point() +
  facet_grid(vs + am ~ gear) + expand_limits(x=0,y=0)+
  theme(strip.placement = "outside")
mg
```

Output is here below
[image: Plot Output]